# How do I interpret 弄りがいこそ

Tags: meaning

Is this the same 甲斐 used in 作り甲斐がある？

> 広大な世界、膨大な職業、幾らでも弄れそうな外装。そんな日本人のクリエイト魂にニトロをぶち込むような**弄りがいこそ**、後に外装人気とも言われる現象を生み出す。

Comment: btw I believe いくらでもい is a typo of something. Could you check it?

Comment: Thanks! Fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's 弄り甲斐 in kanji, so it means "worthiness of playing around", or "hackability". こそ is an emphatic topic marker that replaced は.